# python and python3 command does not point to pyenv global version

Tags: python, pyenv

I had previously installed python 2.7 and python 3 with homebrew.

I added these versions to pyenv

```
ln -s $(brew --cellar python)/* ~/.pyenv/versions
ln -s $(brew --cellar python@2)/* ~/.pyenv/versions
```

When I set the global version with `pyenv global 3.6.5`, I get the following error on running this command

```
➜ python --version
pyenv: python: command not found

The `python' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.15
```

I'd like to setup so that `python` command points to the global version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew's `python` formula is Python 3. To avoid breaking applications which expect the `python` command to run Python 2, `brew install python` does not add a `python` command, only `python3`. This is included in the caveats, visible in `brew info python`:

> Python has been installed as
>     /usr/local/bin/python3
>
> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
>   `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
>     /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

When using homebrew only, it's easy to get `python` to point to Python 3 by adding a line like this to one's shell configuration:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

So, one solution could be to link `pyenv` to that directory instead:

```
ln -s $(brew --prefix)/opt/python/libexec/bin ~/.pyenv/versions/3-brew
```

This would make `python` work. However, it means that `python3.6` *won't* work, because that executable lives back in `$(brew --cellar python)/3.6.5`, so it's not a complete solution. I haven't yet figured out anything that preserves both behaviors without manually adding symlinks to Homebrew's installed Python.